# Thunderbolt Display's audio 'cracking, hissing' noises after El Capitan upgrade

Tags: audio, thunderbolt-display

After an upgrade to El Capitan(*) audio played through the Thunderbolt display gets distorted after a while. This is regardless of the audio source played (Spotify, iTunes, soundcloud web).

Switching the output to internal speakers and back to Thunderbolt display solves the problem for a couple of minutes before the cracking, hissing noises start again (with the actual music audible in the background).

(* It was basically a fresh installation, as the upgrade initially failed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue since El Capitan upgrade (2012 MBA).  No other TB devices connected apart from the display.  A restart seems to help, for a short time, as does switching the audio output from the display to the internal speakers and back again.

Removing all USB peripherals plugged into the display seems to prevent it happening, but is not exactly a "solution".  Other devices are just a Apple USB keyboard, Logitech wired mouse, and a powered USB3 external HDD.

I thought it might be a grounding problem (no idea why the OS upgrade would affect this), but no amount of grounding the aluminum keyboard to the computer casing, or the display casing etc. seems to make a difference.

I am not aware of any core audio plugins installed - any way to find this out?

Comment: Strangely enough, removing USB and Network connections solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have kind of a similar problem. I own a Macbook Pro 13" Mid 2014, and a LGUM95 monitor, this two devices are connected with Thunderbolt. The i have my B&W MM-1 Speakers connected to my monitor with USB. After upgrading to El Capitan, i have a annoying problem. When i start my Mac all works fine, but after some time, my sound suddenly disappear, and if i for example try to start a video on YouTube it won't start. Then i can disconnect my speakers and connect them agin and it then works for some time, until the same starts over again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds suspiciously like:
a) A firmware bug: Resolve this by installing available updates
b) A crowded Thunderbolt bus: Does the problem go away if you remove a device?
c) A Thunderbolt bus with a mixture of TB1 and TB2 devices: The display is TB1 and could benefit from any TB2 devices being moved to a different motherboard TB port rather than being daisy chained from the display

Less likely culprits:
i) The audio codec / enhancements etc. may have changed in 10.11: Wait for a patch, or:
ii) A CoreAudio plugin you have running could be playing badly with 10.11: Remove or patch the plugin!

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the firmware for the mb air and the display are up to date; the display is the only device attached, and the air has only one TB port.. What exactly do you mean with solution ii) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just started having this issue too. Early 2014 Macbook Air with Thunderbolt monitor all firmware and software up to date. Nothing plugged into the Thunderbolt - my USB hard drive has all my music stored on it so unplugging it from Macbook is not an option). Spotify is fine. Only iTunes.

Something I have noticed - with iTunes running all other sound (e.g. skype) is distorted so badly it's nothing more than a crackle. With playback stopped skype sound becomes clear.

The audio starts fine then very quickly distorts and gets progressively worse until eventually only clicks and hisses are audible.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Please refrain from adding comments in the Answer section, this is for answers to the questions.  If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).  See [ask] for more info on how to ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the HDD bracket on a MBP 13" 2012 solved this issue. Bracket issues slow down the access time to the HDD.

Here's how to do it with the help from [iFixit](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2012+Hard+Drive+Cable+Replacement/10379).com

Answer (score 0):

Charge your macbook with it's own power cable, don't use the thunderbolt display's magsafe cable. By using the independent cable charger to plug my laptop it completely stopped the noise of the thunderbolt screen.

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here - 2013 Macbook Pro Retina. If I pause for a few seconds, then play again, the audio then recovers. Not a 'solution' though!